# Why my Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 show JetBrains icon in my Windows task bar?

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Uninstall and clear data (remove some directories manually) take no effect. Always show the black icon. (expected is the compasses icon).

[image: JetBrains icon]